# Big Number Sorting in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, sorting, ecmascript-6

Let me know the difference between two code snippets for sorting an Array.

**Snippet 1** -

```
function bigSorting(unsorted) {
    return unsorted.sort((a, b) => a - b);

}
```

**Snippet 2** -

```
function bigSorting(unsorted) {
    return unsorted.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.length == b.length) {
            return a > b ? 1 : -1;
        }

        return a.length - b.length;
    });

}
```

I am having this file - [1000 Items to be in an Array](http://codepad.org/IvxUAFEm), Snippet 2 will be able to sort the data but Snippet 1 won't.

---

FYI -

Problem Statement -

Consider an array of numeric strings where each string is a positive number with anywhere from to digits. Sort the array's elements in non-decreasing, or ascending order of their integer values and return the sorted array.

Example

Return the array ['1', '3', '150', '200'].

Function Description

Complete the bigSorting function in the editor below.

bigSorting has the following parameter(s):

string unsorted[n]: an unsorted array of integers as strings
Returns

string[n]: the array sorted in numerical order
Input Format

The first line contains an integer, , the number of strings in .
Each of the  subsequent lines contains an integer string, .

Constraints

Each string is guaranteed to represent a positive integer.
There will be no leading zeros.
The total number of digits across all strings in  is between  and  (inclusive).

Comment: Those numbers are too large for javascript. It's likely that the second snippet treats them as strings and not numbers.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yup thats fine..but how `if (a.length == b.length) {
            return a > b ? 1 : -1;
        }
` the condition `if` don' break here..bcoz the numbers are too long in that scenario as well ?

Comment: The numbers in the file... is there only one number per line?

Comment: If the number has a length of 17 or more then it won't work

Comment: Cast these numbers to [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) before making any comparisons and give that a try. Like evolutionxbox mentioned, the problem could be that they are being treated as strings.

Answer (score 3):

Use BigInt() to sort them as numbers:

```
    function bigSorting(unsorted) {
         return unsorted.sort((a, b) => (BigInt(a) > BigInt(b))? 0 : -1 );
    }
    bigSorting(unsorted).forEach(i=>console.log(i));
```

**Updated BIN:**

[Working solution in JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/tozakumofa/edit?js,console)

Comment: Nice haha I just suggested to OP to cast them to BigInt. Nicely done.

Comment: The "Working solution" link reports an error to me: `TypeError: Cannot convert a BigInt value to a number at Array.sort (<anonymous>)` - (using Chrome)

Comment: @PeterB - Interesting...Works fine for me. Let me check it. (works on my machine! Haha)

Comment: Yep, worked fine for me. @PeterB - what browser are you using?

Comment: @RandyCasburn Using Chrome 89.0.4389.114 on Windows 10, and I'm not logged in to JS Bin. Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnQ3D.png. Fails in Firefox v-latest + Edge v-latest as well.

Comment: @RandyCasburn : Yes I tried this but it failed in node env.

Comment: @PeterB As it turns out, in strict mode BigInt won't down convert to a Number. So I changed the comparator to return a literal integer to fix that issue. it works now.

Comment: @Nesh - please see the updated bin for a working solution that also works in Node.

Comment: Note that this introduces an instability into the (modern) JS engines' otherwise stable sort. (https://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/gzvptya6/).  It really needs to be able to return a positive value, a negative value, or zero depending on whether the first value is greater than, less than, or equal to the second one.  This conflates greater than with equal to.   While this probably doesn't matter with numeric values, it's a good habit to be in.

Comment: @ScottSauyet - Good points (and I did consider). Likewise, your over-reliance on  Chrome or FF will introduce, not unstable results, but outright failure modes without considering other browsers. Your Fiddle does not work on Safari on MacOS because `static`s are not supported on those platforms (which I happen to be using) - :-) - do appreciate the insight though.

Comment: The point wasn't the actual test, which I just hacked together as something to explain the issue. In fact I almost never use JS classes.  The problem is the way the comparator passed to `sort` should function.  (And by the way, I use Brave.)  I did just fix the Fiddle.  Don't have a Mac to test on though.  Let me know if it works now.

Comment: Works perfectly without `static`. Brave is a good choice, but I do so enjoy the biometric keychain access on my Mac with Safari. I eat the downsides.